# Slow mySQL query when using two indexed columns

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have a mySQL table (myISAM) containing approximately two million rows - name, address, company data. The first name and surname are held in separate columns, so I also have a second table (linked by the primary key of the first) which holds a single full name column.

The first name, surname, and company name (among others) in the first table are indexed, as is the full name column in the secondary table.

Taking this query as a starting point:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.ID = table_b.ID WHERE....
```

searching exact match or even after-like on the name columns works in milliseconds:

```
....table_a.first_name = 'Fred'
....table_a.surname = 'Bloggs'
....table_b.fullname = 'Fred Bloggs'
....table_a.first_name LIKE 'Mike%'
```

just a few examples.

Throw the COMPANY NAME in there as well..... the query suddenly takes 15 to 20 seconds:

```
....table_a.first_name = 'Fred' OR table_a.company_name = 'Widgets Inc'
```

for example

Both fields are indexed, it's an exact match.... why would the addition of a second indexed search column slow things down so much? Have I missed something about my table design?

Examples follow - there are a few other tables joined but I'm not sure these are affecting performance:
Example of name-only query which returns in 0.0123 seconds:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    webmaster.dupe_master_id AS webmaster_id, 
    webmaster.first_name, 
    webmaster.family_name, 
    webmaster.job_title, 
    webmaster.company_name, 
    webmaster.address_1, 
    webmaster.address_2, 
    webmaster.town_city, 
    webmaster.state_county, 
    webmaster.post_code, 
    webmaster.email, 
    webmaster.ignored, 
    countries.country_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT titles.code ORDER BY code ASC) AS sub_string, 
    '' AS expo_string 
FROM 
    (`webmaster`) 
    LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`country_id` = `webmaster`.`country_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `red_subscriptions` ON `red_subscriptions`.`webmaster_id` = `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` AND red_subscriptions.subscription_status_id = 2 
    LEFT JOIN `titles` ON `titles`.`title_id` = `red_subscriptions`.`title_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `webmaster_tags` ON `webmaster_tags`.`webmaster_id` = `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`tag_id` = `webmaster_tags`.`tag_id` 
    INNER JOIN `webmaster_search_data` ON `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` = `webmaster_search_data`.`webmaster_id` 
WHERE 
    (full_name = '<name>') 
GROUP BY 
    `webmaster`.`dupe_master_id` 
LIMIT 50
```

Add in company_name (also indexed) and the query time goes through the roof:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    webmaster.dupe_master_id AS webmaster_id, 
    webmaster.first_name, 
    webmaster.family_name, 
    webmaster.job_title, 
    webmaster.company_name, 
    webmaster.address_1, 
    webmaster.address_2, 
    webmaster.town_city, 
    webmaster.state_county, 
    webmaster.post_code, 
    webmaster.email, 
    webmaster.ignored, 
    countries.country_name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT titles.code ORDER BY code ASC) AS sub_string, 
    '' AS expo_string 
FROM 
    (`webmaster`) 
    LEFT JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`country_id` = `webmaster`.`country_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `red_subscriptions` ON `red_subscriptions`.`webmaster_id` = `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` AND red_subscriptions.subscription_status_id = 2 
    LEFT JOIN `titles` ON `titles`.`title_id` = `red_subscriptions`.`title_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `webmaster_tags` ON `webmaster_tags`.`webmaster_id` = `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`tag_id` = `webmaster_tags`.`tag_id` 
    INNER JOIN `webmaster_search_data` ON `webmaster`.`webmaster_id` = `webmaster_search_data`.`webmaster_id` 
WHERE 
    (full_name = '<name>' OR company_name '<name>') 
GROUP BY 
    `webmaster`.`dupe_master_id` 
LIMIT 50
```

EXPLAIN on full_name only:

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  webmaster_search_data   ref webmaster_id,full_name  full_name   302 const   94  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  webmaster   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   webmaster_search_data.webmaster_id  1
1   SIMPLE  countries   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   webmaster.country_id    1
1   SIMPLE  red_subscriptions   ref webmaster_id,subscription_status_id webmaster_id    4   webmaster_search_data.webmaster_id  1
1   SIMPLE  titles  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   red_subscriptions.title_id  1
1   SIMPLE  webmaster_tags  ref webmaster_id    webmaster_id    4   webmaster_search_data.webmaster_id  5
1   SIMPLE  tags    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   webmaster_tags.tag_id   1   Using index

Explain when company_name is added:

1   SIMPLE  webmaster   index   PRIMARY,company_name    dupe_master_id  4   NULL    2072015 Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  countries   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   webmaster.country_id    1
1   SIMPLE  red_subscriptions   ref webmaster_id,subscription_status_id webmaster_id    4   webmaster.webmaster_id  1
1   SIMPLE  titles  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   red_subscriptions.title_id  1
1   SIMPLE  webmaster_tags  ref webmaster_id    webmaster_id    4   webmaster.webmaster_id  5
1   SIMPLE  tags    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2   webmaster_tags.tag_id   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  webmaster_search_data   eq_ref  webmaster_id,full_name  webmaster_id    4   webmaster.webmaster_id  1   Using where

Comment: What does [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) say about your query? Please add this info to your question.

Comment: What is your combinaison of AND and OR? Maybe the first query return a hundred rows, and throwing a company name with an OR return a million row? What are the count expected of each query?

Comment: Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE [tablename]` for both tables and the full queries, this will make answering much easier:)

Comment: @Vyktor I'll post the full query + an explain in a few minutes.

Comment: example queries and explains added

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot use two indexes at once. When you throw in the company name, MySQL cannot use the index on Firstname, Lastname anymore because now there are more columns it has to check to get an exact result.

It is probably doing a full table scan.

You could split your queries up by doing a Union, that way you can use both columns with the index.

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM table_a 
  INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.ID = table_b.ID 
  WHERE table_a.first_name = 'Fred' 
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM table_a 
  INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.ID = table_b.ID
  WHERE table_a.company_name = 'Widgets Inc'
) sub;
```

Each query should be evaluated separately and use the adequate index. THe UNION will take care of doubles, so you will in the end have the same result.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but I'll give this a go. The query is generated in-code so could be fun getting the nesting etc. right!